# Capture multi-values for a column to one with same name but different primary key

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask if the following is possible. So basically, I am making a game page. Everything is working fine but I have this game known as Call of Duty: Black Ops and it has two different genres.

My table (game):
[the image for my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Y09.png)

As shown in the table, COD has two primary keys but different GenreID. 
Is there a way for me to display both the genreID even though they have different gameID ? thank you!

Comment: You need a separate table containing `(gameId, genreId)`—see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form.

Comment: I have a table of that called game_genre which includes gameID, gameName, genreID and GenreName.

Comment: `GameName` is dependent on `GameID`, and `GenreName` is dependent on `GenreID`—so placing those attributes in this new table violates [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).  Instead, put `GameName` only in the `Games` table; and `GenreName` only in the `Genres` table; and then the pairing of `(GameID, GenreID)` are the only columns that you need in this new `GameGenres` table.

Comment: but how can that allow two genrenames to come out? i did that too

Comment: with two separate records in the `GameGenres` table, eg `(20, 1)` and `(20, 2)` if game 20 is in genres 1 and 2.

Comment: oh i see, so i just select genreid from genre where gameid = 20 then i will get both out. Okay Thank you so much!